# Making my own API, review this please

Tags: api, oauth

I really don't understand this OAuth authentication method, so I just gave up. The reason I decided to create my own was because I believe the functions my API will carry out aren't that big, it'll mostly be able to read data and occasionally write too.

Here's my plan for API requests on my site.

Consumer API Request with a *special key* > User Authorise's Application (if not done so already) > Callback URL to consumer upon authorising > Run API Script on provider > return result to consumer.

Is this okay? This is my first time writing an API for any site, so I'm here to learn.

Answer (score 3):

In general, I would say that if you're trying to roll your own authentication protocol because you don't understand the existing ones, you're making a Fatal Mistake™.

The only time you should consider doing this is if you totally understand the protocol in question, and require some functionality from it that you are 100% sure it does not offer.  OAuth is complicated because it has to be.  Certain requirements exist to make sure it's secure.

In writing your own without understanding the complexity, you're setting yourself up to fail.